# Is there a way to completely delete a specific Object Variable from an existing GameObject?

Tags: unity, gameobject

When my GameObjects have run their course, I would like to scrub them and prepare them to go back into an Object Pool.

Each of my main GameObjects has around ~20-30 Object Variables.  Part of the scrubbing process is cleaning up all of the Object Variables.

I can reset some of the Object Variables to their default values, or even set them equal to Null.

But some of my Object Variables aren't always used for every GameObject.

Is there a way to completely delete a specific Object Variable from an existing GameObject?  Or is my only option to set it to a default and/or Null value...

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What do you think would the difference be between "setting the value to default and/or null" and "completely deleting" the variable?

Comment: I was just wondering if there's a way to delete an Object variable, so it disappears from the long list of Object Variables in the Inspector.  If there's not, then that's OK and I'll just re-initialize them (or set them to null, if there's no value that makes sense).

Comment: Well, there is the [`[HideInInspector]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html) property, but that one isn't conditional and it can't be added or removed at runtime.

Comment: Got it, ok I will just re-initialize the relevant object variables and set the rest to Null.  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're using one pool for many different types of objects with different needs, instead of a single pool per object type. If you put all the objects that need a specific set of behaviours/components into one pool, and those that need different behaviours/components into a different pool, then you shouldn't have such a long list of variables on each one or a surplus of variables not needed for a given use.

Comment: @DMGregory The 20-30 variables are all for the same type of object... I'm making a word game to teach kids how to read, and each object is a letter/group of letters.  I will do some housekeeping and remove/merge some of the variables, but it will still probably be at least 15-20 object variables when I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

C# is a strongly typed language. That means every object is of a certain type, and that type determines what variables it has. Every object retains its type throughout its lifetime; you can not change the type of an object, you can only recreate it as a new object of a different type. And because the type of an object is unchangeable, and the type says what variables an object has, you can not add or remove variables of an existing object. All you can do is set the values of those variables to something that is to be interpreted as "initial", "unknown" or "undefined".

However, a general note about object pools: In many cases there is no reason to clean up an object when you move it to the pool. An object in the pool should not be doing anything, so its values shouldn't matter. When you retrieve the object from the pool, you are going to overwrite most of its values anyway. So there is no point in overwriting them twice. So the method you use to retrieve an object from the pool can fulfill both purposes: Overwrite those values that are required for the new identity of the object, and clear those which are not.

Comment: Thanks!  And totally agree on not having to scrub every object variable before putting an object back in the pool... great point!  Will just have to doublecheck that my initialization script consistently overwrites all the important object variables.